# Display next delivery day based on time rules in Woocommerce products loop only cake category product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

i want display time based on  in Woocommerce products loop for only **cake category not a frames category**

1. if customer order after 6.00pm delivery date show tomorrow.
2. Basically, we offer same day delivery on everyday, for orders placed before 6pm.
3. if orders placed after 6.00pm delivery day tomorrow.
4. timezone-Asia/Kolkata.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Date() Function like this:

```
function BN_delievery_day() {
    date_default_timezone_set("'Asia/Kolkata'");  
    $thresshold = '1800';         
    $time =date("Hi");
    
    if ($time < $thresshold && $time > '0000') {
    $delivery_day = 'today';
    }
    else {
    $delivery_day = 'tomorrow';
    }
      
       echo 'Delievery: '.$delivery_day;
}

add_action ('woocommerce_share','BN_delievery_day');
```

Add this to the functions.php of your child theme.

To target the category, you can use:

```
if( has_term( 'cake', 'product_cat' ) ) {
}
```